# different number format in iReport and Jasper Server

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

i created report in iReport, where is text field with format:

```
new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00").format($F{NUMBER}) + " €"
```

In iReport result is 1 234,56 €, which is OK. I am in Slovakia and this is ordinary format here.
In Jasper Server is result 1,234.56 € which is not OK.

Other question: There is still Sk (Slovak Crown) set for Slovakia. Is it possible to set it for EUR ?

Could you help me, what to set where ?

Thanks

Comment: Is your java expression class for that field java.math.BigDecimal?

Comment: It was not, but when I change it, it is the same. In iReport OK, in Jasper wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hard-code the format to use comma for the thousands separator, it's not possible that iReport would ignore this. It sounds like you have not done what you think.

But it seems likely that you need to set the JasperReports Server to use a different locale. You could edit this file:

```
WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
```

You'll find the locale section. Add what you need for Slovakia. Then you can choose this locale on the login page.

Or it might be helpful to set the locale in Tomcat's startup script (or whatever app server you are using). These Java parameters might solve your problem (of course you won't want en_US... but those are the parameters):

```
java -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped set the locale in Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

I have an older version of jasperserver deployed in one of my clients and upgrading it would be a bit of a pain. I'm experiencing the same thing with iReport 4.1.1. My locale is pt_BR and  I didn't really want to change my server locale.

I've noticed that iReport is smart (or dumb) enough to not add the class attribute to the textFieldExpression class (I am guessing it guesses from the variable/field type). Jasperserver (at least the version I'm using anyway), on the other hand, does not apply the pattern to numbers if you don't specify the class for that expression.

In other words: iReport generates this markup and renders it as expected:

```
<textField pattern="###,###,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="1293" y="0" width="92" height="20"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
        <font isBold="true"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{my_var}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

You can assume that **my_var** is a BigDecimal. This field does not get rendered correctly in the server, as it simply ignores the pattern (maybe because it assumes all fields are Strings?) unless you specify the expression class for the textFieldExpression:

```
<textField pattern="###,###,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="1293" y="0" width="92" height="20"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
        <font isBold="true"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$V{my_var}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Note the **class="java.math.BigDecimal"** in the second last line. It sucks that I had to manually edit the jrxml file, but at least Jasperserver renders my report properly.